# ERROR compiling vertex shader! ERROR: 0:3: 'attrubte' : syntax error

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

I'm having trouble with shaders and am new to WebGL. I've searched for the error for hours and just can't find it. I am following a tutorial and compared my code to that of the tutorial author, it matches exactly, and his code runs fine in his demo, but for some reason does not run on mine. Here is

```
  var vertexShaderText =
    [
    'precision mediump float;',
    '',
    'attrubte vec2 vertPosition;',
    '',
    'void main()',
    '{',
    '   gl_Position = vec4(vertPosition, 0.0, 1.0);',
    '}'
    ].join('\n');

    var fragmentShaderText =
    [
    'precision mediump float;',
    '',
    'void main()',
    '{',
    'gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);',
    '}'
    ].join('\n');

    var InitDemo = function() {
        console.log('this is working');

        var canvas = document.getElementById('game-surface')
        var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');

        if (!gl){
        console.log('WebGL not supported, falling back on experimental-webgl');
        gl = canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');

        }
        if (!gl) {
            alert('Your browser does not support WebGL')
        }


        gl.clearColor(0.75, 0.85,0.8,1.0)
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT  |  gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // 
        // Create shaders
        // 
        var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
        var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderText);
        gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderText);



        gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
        if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
            console.error('ERROR compiling vertex shader!', gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
            return;
        }

        gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
        if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
            console.error('ERROR compiling fragment Shader!', gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
            return;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error message:

> ERROR compiling vertex shader! ERROR: 0:3: 'attrubte' : syntax error

There is a typo in your vertex shader program. The keyword is `attribute` and not `attrubte`.

Change to

```
attribute vec2 vertPosition;
```

to solve the issue.